# Do I need all the nokia qt DLLs?

Tags: c++, qt, dll, exe, nokia

If I release a program built in the QT framework:

1) How do I find which DLL's I need to include

2) Do I HAVE to include DLL's or is the code compiled into the EXE

The program is very simple, just a interface with a two text boxes and a button.

I just don't want to have 5MB in QT DLL's for a 100KB EXE file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you link statically (which requires a static Qt, which you'll need to build from source), you need to ship DLLs.
To find out which DLLs are needed, you can use something like [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/), or check the link line when compiling/in the generated Makefile.
Usually its QtCore, QtGui and whatever you configured explicitly in the .pro file, like `CONFIG += xml`,  `CONFIG += webkit`, or `CONFIG += network` etc.

A few MBs I'd expect in every case, even if your own code is just a few KB (its only a few KB because Qt does all the heavy lifting, after all).

Answer (score 0):

If you link static libraries into your executable you won't need DLLs.

If you link shared libraries into your executable you will need DLLs.

You can tell which ones you're compiling against if you look at the command line and see /MT or /MD for static and shared respectively.

If the license allows you to include static libraries, that is generally a much simpler solution.